# Hide certain numbers when picking SMS recipients

Tags: sms, samsung-galaxy-s-3, go-sms

So many of my contacts have both home and cell numbers in my contact list. But when I am typing in names I  the recipient field go sms pro), I don't really want to see numbers that cannot receive texts, like home phone numbers. Is there a logical way to manage this?